# Writing to file blocks sometimes

Tags: java, android, file, buffer

I implemented a download manager, which works fine except that I noted one thing, sometimes the thread blocks for a while(50 milliseconds to up to 10 seconds) when writing to files, I am running this program on Android(Linux based), my guess is if there're some kind of **buffer** in the OS level that needs to be flushed, and my writing actually writes to that buffer, and if that buffer is full, writing needs to wait.

My question is what is the possible reason that could cause the blocking?

Comment: Does java.io.BufferedWriter also work on Android?

Comment: "...what is the possible reason that could cause the blocking?" - Without seeing your code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Writing to flash is an operation that sometimes experiences delays.  Android is a mutlitasking system but many implementations have a "one at a time" bottleneck in the implementation details of the flash interface, so it is possible to see poor performance in some circumstances.  The 10 seconds is obviously surprising and makes one wonder what else might be running on the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IO is well known to be a 'blocking' activity, hence your question should be 'what should you do while your program is busy waiting for IO to complete'

Adopting some of the well known concurrency strategy and event-based programming pattern is a good start

Comment: It's been quite while that I found out the cause of problem, I comment here in case someone else may find this helpful. It was indeed because of **busy IO**. I was using multithreads to download the file, if the target file is too large, a large sparse file needs to be created(with seek) before the threads can start writing the file, so the `write` part blocks, I tried keeping all threads writing to the beginning of the file to avoid creating a file so large at first, by doing that, I need a config file to keep the offsets and the bytes written of each thread. Now everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**-** I have done the writing and reading of files in the following way and never encountered any probs.

**Eg:**

```
File f = new File("Path");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

**-** You can alternatively try out the `NIO` package in Java.